# Powershell window size inconsistency

Tags: powershell

I have two scripts, Menu.Ps1 and MyScript.Ps1.

I open the Menu.Ps1 from an elevated shortcut with the below 'Target' and 'Start in' information:

> Target: %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe &
> '%UserProfile%<ScriptPath.PS1>'
>
> Start in: "%Userprofile%<ScriptPath>"

The first thing the Menu script does is change the window size using:

```
$RawUI = $Host.UI.RawUI
$NewWindowSize = $RawUI.WindowSize
$NewWindowSize.Width = 60
$NewWindowSize.Height = 30

$RawUI.set_WindowSize($NewWindowSize)
```

The Menu script is there to easily call other scripts that are needed.  After entering your selection in the Menu script it calls MyScript.ps1 using:

```
$ScriptPath = <ScriptPath>\MyScript.ps1
start-process powershell ". '$ScriptPath'"
```

The window and text from the script opened using `Start-Process` is always larger than the one that was opened from the shortcut despite leveraging the same syntax at the beginning of both scripts.

**Why do they open up as different sizes, and how do I get them to open as identical sizes?**

Even more interesting is if I check the window size using `$host.ui.rawui` they output identical windowsizes, but the maxphysicalwindowsize and buffersize is different.

Changing the buffersize did nothing, and it won't let me edit the MaxPhysicalWindowSize.

As a last ditch effort I set all the properties of `$Host.UI.RawUI` in both scripts  identical as best as possible, but it did not make them the same size either.

If I call the Menu.Ps1 script using `Start-Process` I get the same size windows as when calling MyScript.ps1 using `Start-Process`.  It seems like start-process, or the way I am starting my script with the shortcut is causing problems, but I don't see how.

Any ideas or guidance as to how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I found the issue was font related.  Since the window size is based off of a number of characters, the size of the font affects the windowsize.  The part I don't understand is why are there two different defaults for powershell and how to harmonize them without having to leverage additional code at script start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found, it's font related. Here's what I've observed:

- If **PowerShell** is launched from:

  - `Start Menu`
  - `Search`
  - `WinX` menu

  the font settings are read/saved to the properties of the shortcut (`.lnk` file) located in:

  - `shell:Programs\Windows PowerShell`
- If **PowerShell** is launched from:

  - `Run` dialog
  - `Open PowerShell window here` context menu displayed fron <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right-click</kbd> in background of a folder
  - `Start-Process` in **PowerShell**
  - `Start` in **cmd.exe**

  the font settings are read/saved to the Registry key:

  - `HKCU\Console\%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe`
- If **PowerShell** is launched from a `Taskbar` pin, the font settings are read/saved to the properties of the shortcut (`.lnk` file) located in:

  - `shell:User Pinned\Taskbar`
- If **PowerShell** is launched from a user-created shortcut, the font settings are read/saved to the properties of that shortcut (`.lnk` file).